# How to load data from properties file in Maven?

Tags: java, spring, pom.xml, properties-file

I have migrated to Maven project (using Spring) where I don't need to use my old *.xml config files.

The adaptation was easy but what I still can't figure out is: how to let know to my project that I have properties file and wanna use it?

(If you know how to register properties file in POM, please add some brief description how to load data from this file. (if there is any significant difference in using )

EDIT:

In old project, I had just `spring-mvc-dmo-servlet.xml` config file, where I put every configs (like "scan all components in my projects, cus I don't wanna declare them explicitly"...

If I wanted to let my spring project know I have special file (In this case `countries.properties` with content what I wanna use - I had to put following code into the config file -

```
<util:properties id="countryOptions" location="classpath:../countries.properties" />
```

... only after that, i could wire the content from the file with fields in my classes...

like this

```
@Value("#{countryOptions}") 
private Map<String, String> countryOptions;
```

(but now I don't have any `spring-mvc-dmo-servlet.xml` anymore, now I have only POM.xml and in POM my old expression doesnt work ofc )

So my question is:

What I have to put into my POM to say my spring project "HEY THERE IS SPECIAL FILE !"

And how to wire it (#{countryOptions} or ${countryOptions} or something else)

Comment: I guess the question is less about how to load the files, but how to get them into the java package (JAR, WAR, EAR), right?

Comment: why would maven need to load data from properties file? Isn't it your spring app that needs the data, not maven? or are you talking about packaging, like suggested?

Comment: I am talking about a simple file, where are rows like - friend0=Hubers (next row ) friend1=eis  ... and I simply want to access this file from my class and wire the content... But I am not successful at all :D Before Maven I had to explicitly declare this file in my config *.xml file. Here it is maybe not necessary, maybe I just have to put it into the right folder, but I can't find the answer :D

Comment: @PavelFranta I understood that you have a spring app with xml configuration and you migrated from that to use .properties files. I don't see how maven changes this in any way. Maybe you could rewrite your question to describe in more details as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: my old project was configured in *.xml file... my new project has all configuration in POM.xml but in POM everything is slightly different and I cant use the same expression to "register" my properties.file.

Comment: what "same expression"? we can't know unless you show us the expressions/configuration you have.

Comment: Judging from the comments it is unclear what you are actually asking. I suspect with *old .xml files* you actually mean spring application context files. And the migration is not only to use Maven instead of whatever you used before but also from Spring XML based configuration to a Spring based Java Configuration. So I guess your question has nothing to do with Maven but more on how to use Spring java based configuration. Either way please update your question to be more clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a maven plugin to load the properties from file

One of them is
http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html

EDIT:

In one of our spring boot projects, the path to a property file is passed trough command line using the option:

```
--spring.config.location=$DIRECTORY/application.properties
```

Then to get the values:

```
/** The property to get. */
@Value("${property.to.get}")
private String propertyToGet;
```

You can also take a look at @PropertySource annotation

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
```

See https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: that was first thing what I did BUT I have not been able to access anything (in other words I did not know how to do it or where to place the file itself )

Comment: Where do you want to use values? In maven Pom or in java Spring app?

Comment: Hello Mumrah81, answer is on my EDIT

Comment: Hello Mumrah81, for your suggestion i probably need to use spring boot which is not in this case. :/

Comment: @Pavel: PropertySource annotation is part of spring, you don't need springboot to use it